# Parse string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an element on the form:

```
<img src="/media/BodyPart_7d0cf57e-a461-44fd-903f-ce77b005e299/300/0" class="media-item">
```

I want to extract the `Bodypart_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Here ix the mask of the string `"/{anyt-ext-here}/BodyPart_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/{any-number-here}/{any-number-here}"`

What is the best day of doint it?

Comment: Probably `string.match(/bodypart_[^\/]+/i)` will do. If no match is found, it returns *null*, otherwise an array of the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```js
var output= document.querySelector("#output");
var img= document.querySelector(".media-item"); //assuming there is only the wanted img of this class

var extracted_string= img.src.match(/BodyPart[^\/]*/);
if( extracted_string )
  output.innerHTML= extracted_string;
else
  output.innerHTML= "no match found";
```

```html
<img src="/media/BodyPart_7d0cf57e-a461-44fd-903f-ce77b005e299/300/0" class="media-item">

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: getting error here: `img.src.match(/BodyPart[^\/]*/)` saying `img.src` underfined. I cehcked on debugger `img` has outerHTML `outerHTML: "<img src="/media/BodyPart_......."` I actually used jquery `$(this).prev("img.media-item");` insteard of `document.querySelector` probably that is the reason why `src` in uderfined

Comment: was trying `$(img)attr("src")` - not avaliable

Comment: jquery returns an array of all element matching the selector, even if there is only one returned. So you can use: `$(this).prev("img.media-item")[0]` to get the img element, then you will be able to get the src attribute with: `$(this).prev("img.media-item")[0].src`, and `$(this).prev("img.media-item")[0].src.match(/BodyPart[^\/]*/)` to get the URL part requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var input   = "<img src=\"/media/BodyPart_7d0cf57e-a461-44fd-903f-ce77b005e299/300/0\" class=\"media-item\">";
var matches = input.match(/^<img src=.*\/(BodyPart\_\w{8}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{12})\//);

alert(matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
BodyPart_7d0cf57e-a461-44fd-903f-ce77b005e299
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.split()` , `.filter()`

```js
var img = document.querySelectorAll("img[src*=BodyPart]")[0];
var res = img.src.split("/").filter(function(src, i) {
            return /BodyPart/.test(src)
          })[0];
console.log(res);
```

```html
<img src="/media/BodyPart_7d0cf57e-a461-44fd-903f-ce77b005e299/300/0" class="media-item">
```